# Should local Documentation match reference.wolfram.com?

Tags: documentation

I've searched here for similar questions but was unable to find any. I have a specific example where my local documentation does not match the documentation on http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ (in this case, [`Databin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Databin.html?q=Databin)). I've tried using a few, but not all, of the additional forms for `Databin` online. The forms I've tried worked, so my mma functionality seems to match the online documentation. There may be other cases. I'm just curious if this is normal? If not, is there a way to get them synchronized? I'm using mma v10.0.2. I have `AllowDocumentationUpdates` set to `True` in my global preferences.

Here's a sceen grab of my local documentation:

[image: Local Documentation for Databin]

Comment: I am running V10.0.2 on OS X. My documentation for `DataBin` and related topics updated when I opened *Mathematica* a little after I got an RSS feed announcement that Data Drop had gone live. I think when  *Mathematica* starts up, it contacts a WRI server and updates the documentation when updates are available.

Comment: @m_goldberg: OK. I think I'm going to have to contact WRI support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After contacting WRI support, I received the following response:

> The local documentation updates with Wolfram Mathematica. The most updated documentation would be the version on http://reference.wolfram.com/language/. The documentation update option may be irrelevant and has already been reported.

So, local documentation only updates when Mathematica is updated. The option setting is apparently unused.